# How to check network on off

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, reachability

How to check for the condition where network is on or off
Reachability Network in Xamarin  for IOS.

I am new to xamarin.
how can check for Reachability for network connection on or off using C# Xamarin .

@All
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Xamarin has a reachability sample](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/reachability/detect_if_network_is_available/)

Comment: NetworkStatus internetStatus = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus();
if(!Reachability.IsHostReachable("http://google.com")) {
// Put alternative content/message here
Console.WriteLine ("network not connected");
}
else{
Console.WriteLine ("network connected!!!");
// Put Internet Required Code here
}                                                                      I used above code Reachability static class, run the application with connected Wifi on.  its calling "Network not Connected."  and i turn off wifi (LAN wire is not at all connected). its calling same "Network not Connected."